# I tried having a preview before uploading multiple images using angularjs but none of them is displayed?

Tags: html, angularjs, filereader

I tried using the following code . Only the image's name which i selected was displayed. I want to display them one after the other

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().SelectFile(event)" />
    <hr />
    <img ng-src="{{image.PreviewImage}}"
         ng-show="image.PreviewImage != null" alt=""
         ng-repeat="image in list" style="height:200px;width:200px" />
</div>
```

here is my angularjs code

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.list=[];
    $scope.SelectFile = function (e) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $scope.image.PreviewImage = e.target.result;
            $scope.list.push(e.target.result);
            $scope.$apply();
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    };
});
```